# With useEffect react hook its running to infinte loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

```
 const addData = async () => {
    const result = await axios.post(
      "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?_limit=10",
      { id: uuidv4(), title: title, completed: false }
    );
    setTodos((prevTodos) => [...prevTodos, result.data]);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    addData();
  }, [addData]);
```

I want to call the function "addData" on form submit

Comment: put the whole `addData` function inside `useEffect` and call it. You may also need to put things inside dependency array

Comment: I did that earlier, but then I cannot call that addData function from outside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove dependency from the useEffect as i mention below, useEffect will execute when it's dependency value change, and you are making change to same dependency of useEffect inside useEffect,

```
useEffect(() => {
    addData();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to call the function "addData" on form submit

If that's when you want to run it, then i don't see why you need a `useEffect` at all. Just call addData on form submit.

```
const Example = (props) => {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  const addData = async () => {
    const result = await axios.post(
      "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?_limit=10",
      { id: uuidv4(), title: title, completed: false }
    );
    setTodos((prevTodos) => [...prevTodos, result.data]);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={addData}>
      {/* etc */}
    </form>
  )
}
```

Comment: thank you.. I removed useEffect and I did similar to yours but now the "id" is not generating an unique one .. key = "201" is remaing same everythime I am submitting the form